# Thriller of man chasing a woman while time is frozen

Tags: story-identification, movie

Please help me to identify this movie, I think it was from the late 70's. I just remember a woman is commuting on the subway when suddenly the time is slowly freezing. When the time is completely frozen a man emerges and chases her, she runs but obviously nobody can see/hear/help her.  Only she and the man are not affected by the time while everything else is standing still. She manages to escape and the time slowly starts to flow again.

Comment: *Friday the 13th: The Series* had an episode called *13 O'clock* that was entirely about time freezing on a subway (it's available [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NCGIrlst660)). It's from 1989, though, and obviously not a film.

Comment: Thank you Walt, that's it!  I will answer my own question in order to mark it as solved.

Comment: Honorable mention: [*The Girl, The Gold Watch, and Everything*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Girl,_the_Gold_Watch_%26_Everything_(film)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Friday the 13th: The Series, episode 13 O'clock (as Walt commented on the original question).